# print a matrix that is spiraling out from a given row and column using multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array

I was recently asked this question in an interview. After spending hours, I did come up with a single threaded implementation but, I feel it is inefficient and I have no clue about how to make it multi-threaded.

Here is my implementation:

```
public List<Integer> print(int[][] input, int row, int col) {
    int n = input.length;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(n * n);
    int i = row;
    int j = col;
    int steps = 1;
    int k = 0;
    while (true) {

        k = steps;

        while (k > 0) {
            if (inBounds(i, j, n)) {
                result.add(input[i][j]);
            }
            j++;
            k--;
        }

        if (i > row + 4 || j > col + 4)
            break;

        k = steps;

        while (k > 0) {
            if (inBounds(i, j, n)) {
                result.add(input[i][j]);
            }
            i++;
            k--;
        }

        if (i > row + 4 || j > col + 4)
            break;

        steps++;

        k = steps;

        while (k > 0) {
            if (inBounds(i, j, n)) {
                result.add(input[i][j]);
            }
            j--;
            k--;
        }

        if (i > row + 4 || j > col + 4)
            break;

        k = steps;

        while (k > 0) {
            if (inBounds(i, j, n)) {
                result.add(input[i][j]);
            }
            i--;
            k--;
        }
        steps++;

        if (i > row + 4 || j > col + 4)
            break;

    }
    return result;
}

boolean inBounds(int i, int j, int n) {
    return (i >= 0 && i <= n - 1 && j >= 0 && j <= n - 1);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is working, you break if i > row + 4 || j > col + 4... why? If the spiral would leave the matrix, do you have to break or do you have to collect the rest of the elements ignoring positions that are outside of the matrix?

Comment: What was the question for which you wrote this code ? Without knowing problem all anybody can do is skip this post.

Comment: @svasa I did mention in the description that I came up with a single threaded implementation for the posted question

Comment: @maraca My mistake, I hard coded the solution for a 5x5 matrix, for a nxn matrix the breaking condition would be  i > row + n-1 || j > col +  n - 1. If the spiral leaves the matrix, you have to collect the rest of the elements ignoring positions that are outside of the matrix

Comment: @mkg90 that makes it more complicated, because if all numbers of the spiral are inside the matrix, then the first, fourth, nineth etc. (the square) indexes are on a diagonal, so you can first detect the ring and then the position. To be able to populate the output array in parallel this is exactly what you need to be able to do, populate index x independently from the others. A formula that takes the index of the output array as input and returns row, col for a n times m matrix when starting at r, c.